# How can i reload data in Table View in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and preserve selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of my Table View Controller for some reasons i should call `reloadData` of my Table View. After this any selection will disappear. Which is proper way to preserve selection of table?

UPD: i tried to do `selectRowAtIndexPath` after i reload table in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but it didn't lead to any result, selection is still missing. But it will work if i will do it in `dispatch_after` block, although it's a very strange solution. I need to do it in a right way.

Comment: just get one boolean flag and store previous row index and when reload table view than check in cellforrowatindexpath check row and check bool flag and if it is selected than do whatever you want to do and set `[cell setSelected:YES]` and in else `[cell setSelected:NO]`

Answer (score 0):

The reload happens during the next layout pass, which normally happens when you return control to the run loop (after, say, your button action or whatever returns).

So one way to run something after the table view reloads is simply to force the table view to perform layout immediately:

```
- (void)reloadTableView
{
   NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
   for (NSIndexPath *path in indexPaths) {
       [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   }
}
```

Or as you said you can use GCD to schedule your after-layout code to run later

```
- (void)reloadTableView
{
   NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      for (NSIndexPath *path in indexPaths) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-selectRowAtIndexPath` with `animated` flag set to `NO` after you call `[tableView reloadData]` inside `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Objective-C:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    [tableView reloadData];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    ...
}
```

Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    ...
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
    ...
}
```

Comment: as i commented in Istvan's answer, it's not working for me, selection will not appear in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    //add you code and reload the table

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" delegate method, keep a reference of your selected indexPath:

```
indexPathReference = indexPath;
```

And after reloading the table view add this line:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathReference animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you must keep a reference to the selected indexPath.
Then you should call `reloadData`

`reloadData` will trigger calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

That's where you check each index with your stored indexPath and set the cell as selected. (`cell.selected = true`)